# How to fix: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) when performing FAISS Search

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, faiss

Here is my code to perform a vector search using FAISS:

```
import faiss
import numpy as np

index = faiss.IndexIDMap(faiss.IndexFlatIP(768))
index.add_with_ids(np.array([vec for vec in vectors]), np.array(range(0, len(floats))).astype(np.int64))
faiss.write_index(index, 'faiss_index')

from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
embedder = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1')


query = 'What is the capital of USA?'
encoded_query = embedder.encode(query, convert_to_tensor=True)
encoded_query = encoded_query.numpy()
distances, ann = index.search(encoded_query, k=2)
```

I get the following Error Message (Value Error):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8804\783780583.py in <module>
----> 1 distances, ann = index.search(encoded_query, k=2)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\faiss\class_wrappers.py in replacement_search(self, x, k, params, D, I)
    325         """
    326 
--> 327         n, d = x.shape
    328         x = np.ascontiguousarray(x, dtype='float32')
    329         assert d == self.d

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can you tell me how to fix this error?

I tried reshaping the encoded_query (768,) to (768, 1). After I do this I get a different error (Assertion Error):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8804\783780583.py in <module>
----> 1 distances, ann = index.search(encoded_query, k=2)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\faiss\class_wrappers.py in replacement_search(self, x, k, params, D, I)
    327         n, d = x.shape
    328         x = np.ascontiguousarray(x, dtype='float32')
--> 329         assert d == self.d
    330 
    331         assert k > 0

AssertionError:
```

---